# ASP.NET MVC Passing a BeginCollectionItem List's Object through AJAX with Javascript Serialize to Controller is passing null

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, serialization

This has been giving me some trouble for the past few days.  I'm going to try to be as detailed as possible with what I want and the issue I'm having.  I tried to simplify my controllers, models, etc as much as I can for the sake of the question.

**Here's the flow of sequences I'm trying to get to work.**

1. Give user a view with inputs for `List<MyObject>` in the main ViewModel
2. User can hit a button to add another row to add another object to that List of objects to post later
3. Hitting the button POSTs the object (in same container) through AJAX from the currently displayed list in order to repeat most of the inputs for the new row (`MyObject`)
4. Controller takes passed `MyObject` and maps some of the prior values to the new object
5. Controller passes back new `MyObject` and ajax appends the result `html` to my table

## The Problem

The Ajax is passing the on-page `MyObject` as `null` (or C# doesn't know how to interpret) to my controller (step 4 above).  I can't seem to get the object passed to the controller through the Ajax call.

## What I've got

Models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // irrelevant properties
    public List<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; } = new List<MyObject>();
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
    public decimal AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
    public List<MySubObject> MySubObjects { get; set; } = new List<MySubObject>();
}

public class MySubObject
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public bool Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller GET:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();

    // for list of checkboxes
    var subObjects = new List<MySubObject>();

    // get subobjects from db
    subObjects.Add(new MySubObject {
        Name = "SubObj1", IsChecked = false
    });
    subObjects.Add(new MySubObject {
        Name = "SubObj12",
        IsChecked = false
    });

    // populate viewModel with a blank MyObject
    viewModel.MyObjects.Add(new MyObject
    {
        MySubObjects = subObjects
    });

    return (viewModel);
}
```

View (and AJAX call):

```
<table id="myObjectInputs">
    @foreach (var obj in Model.MyObjects)
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyObject.cshtml", obj)
    }
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myObjectInputs").on("focus", ".make-new-row", function () {
        var plusButton = $(this);
        var currentArea = plusButton.closest(".myobject-container");

        var serializedData = currentArea.find(":input").serialize();

        // add new row
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: { "myObject": serializedData },
            success: function (html) { $("#myObjectInputs").append(html); }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

EditorTemplates/MyObject.cshtml:

```
@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem
@model LD.Areas.Admin.Models.MyObject

<tbody class="myobject-container" style="border:solid 1px red;">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("MyObjects"))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.AnotherProperty)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.AdditionalProperty)</td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var subObj in Model.MySubObjects)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MySubObject.cshtml", subObj)                  
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- the button that calls the function / AJAX -->
                @Html.ActionLink("+", "NewMyObjectSection", null, new { @class = "make-new-row" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

EditorTemplates/MySubObject.cshtml

```
@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem
@model LD.Areas.Admin.Models.MySubObject

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("MySubObjects"))
{
    <label>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.IsChecked)@Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsChecked, Model.Name)
        <text>&nbsp;</text>
    </label>
}
```

ActionResult called by AJAX: **(this is I'm getting null for MyObject)**

```
public ActionResult NewMyObjectSection(MyObject myObject)
{
    // take passed object values and create a new object based on myObject

    var newObject = new MyObject(); 

    return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyObject.cshtml", myObject);
}
```

## What I've Tried

Some main things that stick out to me are that `BeginCollectionItem` attaches a `GUID` to make the collection items unique, for ex, when my `<tablebody class="myobject-container">` is serialized, it looks like this (this is the result from my real object, Rates == MyObjects):

```
"Rates.index=b589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.OrganismNid=0&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.OrganismName=&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.OrganismUpdateType=New&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.IsPest=false&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.IsPreEmergent=false&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.IsPostEmergent=false&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.IsSafeOn=false&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.HasControl=false&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.HasSuppression=false&ControlTypes.index=bd9d1180-9768-4ca4-8316-fc5cbf62ca97&ControlTypes%5Bbd9d1180-9768-4ca4-8316-fc5cbf62ca97%5D.ControlTypeNid=1&ControlTypes%5Bbd9d1180-9768-4ca4-8316-fc5cbf62ca97%5D.Name=Annual&ControlTypes%5Bbd9d1180-9768-4ca4-8316-fc5cbf62ca97%5D.IsChecked=false&ControlTypes.index=0264b842-5cac-4b1a-8b79-8f9a13a26428&ControlTypes%5B0264b842-5cac-4b1a-8b79-8f9a13a26428%5D.ControlTypeNid=2&ControlTypes%5B0264b842-5cac-4b1a-8b79-8f9a13a26428%5D.Name=Biennial&ControlTypes%5B0264b842-5cac-4b1a-8b79-8f9a13a26428%5D.IsChecked=false&ControlTypes.index=6a344551-add6-4e9b-96e2-59a6fc857327&ControlTypes%5B6a344551-add6-4e9b-96e2-59a6fc857327%5D.ControlTypeNid=3&ControlTypes%5B6a344551-add6-4e9b-96e2-59a6fc857327%5D.Name=Winter%20Annual&ControlTypes%5B6a344551-add6-4e9b-96e2-59a6fc857327%5D.IsChecked=false&ControlTypes.index=91f5c6ff-402e-48ae-8f9c-1131511699a8&ControlTypes%5B91f5c6ff-402e-48ae-8f9c-1131511699a8%5D.ControlTypeNid=4&ControlTypes%5B91f5c6ff-402e-48ae-8f9c-1131511699a8%5D.Name=Perennial&ControlTypes%5B91f5c6ff-402e-48ae-8f9c-1131511699a8%5D.IsChecked=false&ControlTypes.index=3248ec07-09a8-4bf0-b99f-a518807d9636&ControlTypes%5B3248ec07-09a8-4bf0-b99f-a518807d9636%5D.ControlTypeNid=5&ControlTypes%5B3248ec07-09a8-4bf0-b99f-a518807d9636%5D.Name=Top%20Growth%20Control%20Only&ControlTypes%5B3248ec07-09a8-4bf0-b99f-a518807d9636%5D.IsChecked=false&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.BroadcastMin=&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.BroadcastMax=&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.BroadcastChemUnitTypeNid=1&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.BroadcastAreaUnitTypeNid=9&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.SpotMin=&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.SpotMax=&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.SpotChemUnitTypeNid=1&Rates%5Bb589808e-3e99-40f2-827c-58feaa9bebc3%5D.SpotFinalSolutionUnitTypeNid=1"
```

I'm not sure if my controller understands to bind that to my object.

I've tried other methods of passing it, such as stripping out GUIDs and extra junk from the string, passing it as a string and deserializing in C#, and others:

```
var serializedArray = currentArea.find(":input").serializeArray();

//https://www.regextester.com/94410
var regex = new RegExp("(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}");

var stripped = serializedData.replace(/(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}/g, '');

stripped = stripped.replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');

var strung = JSON.stringify({ "modelData": serializedData });
```

At this point I'm at a loss.  This is for a personal passion project and my lack of AJAX / JSON knowledge is really holding me back.  I'm not sure what else to try.  Any pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: There are quite a number of Issues I see with the Code. I don't See a POST controller but I see a post request. Next if you are using a post request you should make use of the FromBody attribute to receive your object

Comment: @jidexl21 I'm not sure what you mean. I can get strings to pass to the 'ActionResult NewMyObjectSection', just not my object.  I can also return an object to the view and it properly in my table with the partial.  How do I do `[FromBody]`?

Comment: the [FromBody] comes before the parameter definition

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult NewMyObjectSection([FromBody] MyObject myObject)
{
    //myObject should be correctly populated from the request

    return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyObject.cshtml", myObject);
}
```

Id Expect the item to come as a Json Object correctly passed in your request to that your myObject is populated automatically

for the request part:

```
    var dat = {
    Id:3,
    Name:7,
    AnotherProperty:"",
    AdditionalProperty:"",
    MySubObjects:[
        //Create sub objects here
    ]
    };


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "youraction",
    data: JSON.stringify(dat),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

})

Comment: I am still getting `null` for the `myObject`. I added the `using System.Web.Http;` library for `[FromBody]`.

Comment: For the record, I do get the JSON string if I make my parameter `[FromBody]string myObject`, but not when it is `[FromBody]MyObject myObject`.  I get the JSON string without `[FromBody]`, as well.

Comment: Nice to know, so all you have to to is work on formatting your request to send the object in a way the controller will understand.

Comment: I'll add an example... it a bit late but just for completeness of the answer

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem I think with the GUIDs and nested lists of objects.  It's adding a lot of extra crap that's messing up the data.  I wouldn't worry about it. I did a kind of hacky javascript workaround and I can convince myself that it's fine. I think I would need to take the `.serialzied()` and manually format the JSON string before passing to get it to bind to the model, and the object is too dynamic to make a "JSONStringFixer" universal for my case.